# ¿Es correcto decir "privacidad pública"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, gramática, sustantivos

El artículo [*Análisis Strava Premium*](http://www.elcorredorerrante.com/2015/02/primeras-impresiones-strava-premium.html) habla de una aplicación que registra los ejercicios que uno hace, ya sea corriendo o en bici. Según cómo configures la cantidad de información que quieres compartir puedes hacer una cosa u otra, de ahí que se diga:

> Otra opción es generar un "mapa de calor" con los trazados que has recorrido a lo largo del tiempo (**siempre que en preferencias tengas privacidad pública**), de forma superpuesta para consultarlos a posteriori y compartir con tus amigos.

Como veis, señalo la frase *siempre que en preferencias tengas privacidad pública* porque el uso de *privacidad pública* lo entiendo, pero me suena fatal.

En efecto, está hablando de que la aplicación permite definir que tu perfil sea público o privado. Y si se decide que sea público, permite hacer X cosa. Sin embargo, si analizamos la palabra en sí:

> [**privacidad**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UD4g0KW)
>   1. f. Cualidad de privado.
>   2. f. Ámbito de la vida privada que se tiene derecho a proteger de cualquier intromisión.

parece que *privacidad* no es algo adjetivable, sino algo absoluto.

Por ello, *privacidad pública* me parece que se usa erróneamente, pero no estoy seguro. ¿Es así?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está claro que la privacidad no puede ser pública. Lo que me parece que ocurre en esa frase es que se ha reducido el texto y ha quedado uno de los extremos (perfil privado) como definitorio de la magnitud. Sería algo parecido a decir:

- altura baja

Sin embargo, esta frase no es contradictoria como "privacidad pública" porque "altura" significa la dimensión. En cambio, "privacidad" no es una dimensión. La dimensión o medida podría ser "grado de privacidad".

Así las cosas, el texto "expandido" podría ser:

> siempre que en "grado de privacidad" diga/tengas/indique(s) "nulo"

o bien

> siempre que en "tipo de perfil" diga/tengas/indique(s) "privado"

Observa que uso comillas para referirme a la función y el valor seleccionados en la aplicación. Si no, se produce una confusión semántica: la persona que usa la aplicación no tiene privacidad pública, sino que tiene el valor "pública" en el rubro "privacidad".

En cuanto a tu comentario:

> privacidad no es algo adjetivable

el sustantivo "privacidad" a veces se usa como "grado de privacidad" y acepta adjetivos:

- mucha / alta privacidad
- poca / escasa privacidad
- privacidad extrema / total

Comment: Gracias por esta respuesta de *calidad alta* ;-) Por cierto, ¿conoces si hay alguna característica de los sustantivos que determine si es _adjetivable_ o no?

Comment: @fedorqui Se habla de la gradación de los adjetivos (NGLE 13.2.2) -- ejemplos de adjetivos no graduables son * *bastante colgante* y * *muy clínico*. No encuentro que se hable de "gradación de los sustantivos". Lo que ocurre es que los adjetivos son modificados mayormente por adjetivos de cantidad o intensidad (eso permite hablar de "adjetivos graduables y no graduables"), mientras que la variedad de adjetivos que pueden acompañar a sustantivos es mucho más amplia. Cuesta encontrar sustantivos no adjetivables.